# How to use a value from a specific column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

UPPER( [value or column]) is the example in the SQL videos on team treehouse.

What they don't explain is how to use a value in a specific column if the same value is in multiple columns.

How do you use a value in a function in MySQL? What if that value is in multiple columns or a different table?

Comment: Start with the basics... A table, several columns, several rows. Do SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example `UPPER( [value or column])`, "value" means a static string. So you can either do UPPER on a random hard-coded string, or you can do it on a column name (as part of a select statement). Nothing to do with values in different columns.

So you could do:

```
SELECT UPPER('mystring') -- will make any old random string uppercase
```

Or something like

```
SELECT UPPER(myCol) from myTable -- will make the contents of myCol uppercase for each row returned from myTable
```

Or even

```
SELECT UPPER(myCol + ' ' + mySecondCol) from myTable -- will make the concatenated contents of myCol and mySecondCol uppercase for each row returned from myTable, and display them in one column in the resultset
```

Assuming the columns are strings (varchars).

Sorry if any of the syntax is a bit wrong, but you get the idea. I can't remember if this is all definitely valid syntax in MySQL (it is in T-SQL, so chances are it won't be far wrong).

The docs for the function in MySQL are here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_upper